# Error with CiviEvent Form

Tags: civievent

Having a few issues with Civievent forms.

Potential registrants are seeing these error messages.

1)Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment
XML data could not be loaded. Make sure you specified the correct path.

2)When is does work and they click process. They see processing in the button and that screen never changes. They never know if it went through or not.

3) Confirmation emails are not being sent.

Any ideas with any of these ?

Answer (score 1):

These error looks like an PHP error. Are you trying these in an fresh copy of CiviCRM ? please get the latest version and try the same

If you have any extension installed in CiviCRM please do disable all the extension and then try the same

Comment: I'm using civicrm 4.6.8 on drupal 7. I disabled any extensions that have to do with events or contributions but I'll give a shot at disabling all of them

Comment: I disables all my extensions. The form seems to work a little better however . When at the Confirmation page one cicks on 'process', they see 'processing' and the thank you page never loads nor does the confirmation email get sent out. This happens only when they pay by CC, if they click on pay later, everything works fine. 
Any tips?

Comment: did you manage to look for PHP error on the server

Comment: I just noticed these 2:
Notice: Array to string conversion in CRM_Contact_BAO_Query::buildQillForFieldValue() (line 5687 of /srv/bindings/.../civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php)
and
Warning: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer in CRM_Utils_Array::value() (line 55 of /srv/bindings/.../civicrm/CRM/Utils/Array.php).

Comment: I think this might be it: Notice: Undefined index: tax_amount in CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Confirm->buildQuickForm() (line 277 of /srv/bindings/.../civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Registration/Confirm.php)

The thing is that I didn't enable tax and invoicing

Comment: these are just notice i don't think so did you enable the Tax and invoicing - did it work - if not please provide me an link with an username and password so i will try - thanks